# Getting height of a char array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to get what's the height of array :

```
main(){
    int a;
    char array[10][10]={
        "45",
        "34",
        "23",
        "12",
    };
    a=strlen(array);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

But when i use `strlen` it just shows length of first line but i want to know how to get how many lines are in that array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "height"?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Number of "rows" I would guess...

Comment: Number of rows up to the one with a zero-length string?

Comment: `size_t height = sizeof array / sizeof *array;`

Comment: sizeof array[0]

Comment: In this case would you want the "height" to be 10 or 4?

Comment: Yeah @EugeneSh is right

Comment: `int n; for (n = 0; n < 10 && array[n][0]; n++);` will set `n` to the index of the first zero-length string (if any, otherwise sets `n` to 10). For the above code, `n` will be set to 4, since `array[4]` has no explicit initializer, so `array[4][0]` will be initialized to the default value 0.

Comment: @Saurabh next time use _different_ dimensions like `char array[10][20]` and say you want 10

Comment: I want answer as 4

Comment: Sorry guys I am noob

Comment: and what you want if `char array[10][10]={ "45", "34", "23", "12", "\0", "123" };` ? 4 or 5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universal way to find the size of an array is `sizeof array / sizeof *array`. This gives the number of items, in your case 10.

If you want to know how many of the 10 that contain a valid string, you should use a sentinel value like for example `""`:

```
char array[10][10]={
        "45",
        "34",
        "23",
        "12",
        "",
    };

// search for used size of the array
size_t i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  if(strcmp(array[i], "")==0)
    break;
}
// here i contains the used size
```

---

(Normally you'd rather have an array `char* strings[n]` though, where each individual read/write string can have a variable length through dynamic allocation. In that case, you would use NULL as sentinel value.)

Comment: please replace 10 by sizeof usage ;-) and _i_ contains but not _size_ ;-)

Comment: @bruno In a real application you would replace all magic numbers with constants.

Comment: `NULL` is not a suitable initializer for a `char` array.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @IanAbbott Yikes, I really ought to compile code before posting. You are correct of course, I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Have an int that stores that data for you so it's easily available anywhere.

**Solution 2:**

Write a function that counts the rows, something like this:

```
int CountRows(array)
{
  int counter = 0;

  while(elementOfArray)
  {
    counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}
```